# OpenPGP key after reboot - Ubuntu

Tags: password, github, openpgp

So I am using OpenPGP which is fine most of the time, however after a reboot if I (or my script) tries a push, it asks for the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key (a GUI window pops up).

After I manually enter the key and enable the "save in password manager" button, it then asks for the password to Unlock Login Keyring. Once those 2 items have been done, it will then work fine until the next reboot.

How can I automate this so it will continue working after a reboot?

Thanks!